# Cannot receive KEYCODE_DEL on WebView in Android 4.1.1

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I want to make `WebView` editable by creating a complex javascript to handle keyboard event. Everything works fine on all Android version except **4.1**. 
In **4.1** I can handle all key events except `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL`. It seems that we cannot handle `KEYCODE_DEL` event for `WebView` in Android 4.1? I am very appreciate if someone can help me on this issue

Thanks

Comment: I am getting the same issue to on 4.1. Anyone have any ideas? It seems it is a bug with 4.1.

Comment: Also, I am using GLSurfaceView, so the problem is not exclusive to WebView.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like an Android bug. A simple workaround that worked for me was to set

```
android:targetSdkVersion="15"
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml

### **EDIT:**

After some more research, I now think that this is not a bug but rather a deliberate change. The `KeyEvent` documentation says:

> As soft input methods can use multiple and inventive ways of inputting
>   text, there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will
>   generate a key event: this is left to the IME's discretion, and in
>   fact sending such events is discouraged. You should never rely on
>   receiving KeyEvents for any key on a soft input method. In particular,
>   the default software keyboard will never send any key event to any
>   application targetting Jelly Bean or later, and will only send events
>   for some presses of the delete and return keys to applications
>   targetting Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier.

In reality though, it still sends events for most key presses except for the Delete key. Since I really needed all key events I came up with this solution:

First, create your own `View` (in my case it was derived from `TextView`) like this:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

  ...

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo editorInfo) {
        editorInfo.actionLabel = null;
        editorInfo.inputType   = InputType.TYPE_NULL;
        editorInfo.imeOptions  = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NONE;

        return new MyInputConnection(this, false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Second, create `MyInputConnection` by subclassing `BaseInputConnection` like this:

```
public class MyInputConnection extends BaseInputConnection { 

    ...


    // From Android 4.1 this is called when the DEL key is pressed on the soft keyboard (and
    // sendKeyEvent() is not called). We convert this to a "normal" key event.
    @Override
    public boolean deleteSurroundingText(int beforeLength, int afterLength) {
        long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime,
                KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL, 0, 0, KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD, 0,
                KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD | KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE | KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION));
        sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), eventTime,
                KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL, 0, 0, KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD, 0,
                KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD | KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE | KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION));
        return true;
    }
```

In your `InputConnection` class you've got good control on what's going on. For example you can override the `commitText()` method to get events about keys of foreign language letters etc.

Comment: You are awesome, this solition helped me a lot

Comment: Does not work for API level 19, Built Target level 19.  The deleteSurroundingText() method simply does not get called at all (Nexus 7 2012 running Android 4.3, default soft keyboard).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can extend webview and override `public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`

Comment: built target 19 doesn't seem to call this either (nexus 7 2012 android 4.4)

Comment: Not a complete solution.  Selecting all the text in javascript seems to let me start deleting on the second press of the backspace key.

Answer (score 0):

Try to capture 'input' event on KEYCODE_DEL.

```
$('#textBox').on('input', function(event) {
    console.log(event, event.keyCode, event.which);
    // it will capture the event, but you will not get the event.keyCode 
    // and event.which.
});
```

For more Details - [backSpace not firing the keyup event in android mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503559/backspace-not-firing-the-keyup-event-in-android-mobile)
or [JQuery: detect change in input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797700/jquery-detect-change-in-input-field)